# Execute C function every 30 min. in Linux / AIX

Tags: c, linux, aix

I've got following Problem: from my Oracle database i get the execution intervall(Every 30/120 min)  and which function has to be executed. I heard using a thread is a Bad idea in AIX , But i also dont Want to use an cronjob.  Ans other possibilities to ver this done ?

Comment: I have to say "using a thread is a bad idea in AIX" sounds strange to me. Why would that be a bad idea? (maybe not for what you wanna do, but anyway)

Comment: someone told me it's not that easy/different in linux and the software should run on both plattforms. I also got the information that it's necessary for such a small software | it could be done much easier

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Oracle sceduler - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover001.htm#ADMIN12354

Comment: you know how its possible to run an c function with this scheduler?
i only read that its possible to run an pl/sql block

Comment: .. or an extermal program